# Send window.location to a variable, which is a URL in string form

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to send window.location to a variable, but my method doesn't seem to be working.

I have one variable that is the query called query and another caller firstPart. I concatenate them and am trying to sent window to that concatenated URL, but it doesn't seem to work.

Here is what I have so far:

```
var query = "hello";
var firstPart = "http://google.com/?=";
window.location.assign(firstPart + query);
```

Comment: What you have works, though `.assign()` isn't necessary (*but it does work!*). `window.location.href = firstPart + query`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do it like this:

```
window.location.href = firstPart + query;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var query = "hello";
var firstPart = "http://google.com/?=";
window.location.href = firstPart + query;
```

More on window location here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.location